# PowerShell Script With Classes won't execute on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, class, pipeline

My test script is really as simple as this:

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory=$PSScriptRoot, $filter="Excel (*.xlsx)| *.xlsx")
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = $filter
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename #return the result
}

Class MyClass
{

}
```

Removing the class, fixes the error. otherwise I get:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> U:\godzilla\Desktop\Scripts de gestion d'utilisateurs\ressources\Excel.ps1
An error occurred while creating the pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

My version of PowerShell is:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.228                                                                                                                                                  
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                        
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                        
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.228                                                                                                                                                 
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                            
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                            
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Please help! Really out of ideas but would like to keep my code clean and uses classes for this project!

Comment: Strange. I have the same PSVersionTable as yours and your scripts work fine to me. Can you open a fresh console and just run `class MyClass { [string]$Text }` to see if there is an error? Did you try to define the class in a module and export it, then use it in the script? [Here's a blog](https://arcanecode.com/2016/04/05/accessing-a-powershell-class-defined-in-a-module-from-outside-a-module/) if you wanna try this way.

Comment: I think I have figured it out... It looks like when the script is saved here:`,PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> U:\godzilla\Desktop\Scripts de gestion d'utilisateurs\ressources\Untitled4.ps1` it fails. The same script here `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> U:\godzilla\Desktop\Untitled4.ps1` works. Tried removing apostrophe, it worked! So it looks like the use of apostrophe in the path throws it off. Can anyone confirm? Why is this happennening ?

Comment: You need to quote your command if there are spaces.. `& 'U:\path\file.ps1'`

Comment: Just to make clear: running directly by execution of file through PS or PS ISE. Not doing it through commands or anything. The same file without class declaration will run just fine. Similarly, the same code with class just before it is saved in ISE will run without issues. Weird bug.